# Chain complex tensor with $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $C$ be a chain complex with integer coefficients.
Then is $C\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ essentially just the same thing as “$C$ with mod $p$ coefficients”?

I can intuitively see why it is true, since any factor of $p$ in $C$  can “move over” to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, where it is “absorbed”.

However, is there any special significance to using the tensor product? Why not just use a simpler notation, something like $C \pmod p$?

Thanks.

Comment: Because tensor notation is more general (for instance, $C\otimes \Bbb Q$ expands to rational  coefficients), less ambiguous (does the mod go on each term in $C$, or on the index, making it a circular chain complex?), and not as much abuse of notation, I'd wager.

Comment: Thanks. What is a index and a circular complex by the way?

Comment: What I meant was that $C$ is actually a chain complex $\cdots \to C_{i+1}\to C_i\to C_{i-1}\to \cdots$, and if you mod out on the indices, then you lump $C_i$ together with $C_{i+p}, C_{i-p}$ and so on in some way. (How do you do that? Product? Tensor product? Are they actually isomorphic, so you just keep one? I guess you're free to choose.) If you do this, then you get a new complex $C'$ given by $$\cdots \to C'_{p-1}\to C'_{p-2}\to \cdots \to C'_{1}\to C'_0\to C'_{p-1} \to \cdots$$which is what I meant by circular.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general theory is [change of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings), in this case using the quotient homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  It does end up being the same as chains with mod-$p$ coefficients.

Beware thinking that $C\pmod{p}$ is "simpler" just because it looks like notation you are used to.  Tensor products are more general (more possibilities for coefficient rings than just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$) and are functorial/natural (get induced maps between chain complexes).